# How to follow META Redirections in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently using the following to follow redirects on a url, but it **doesn't follow META redirections :(**

**How could I do that?**

```
require 'logger'
require 'net/http'

class RedirectFollower
  class TooManyRedirects < StandardError; end

  attr_accessor :url, :body, :redirect_limit, :response

  def initialize(url, limit=5)
    @url, @redirect_limit = url, limit
    logger.level = Logger::INFO
  end

  def logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end

  def resolve
    raise TooManyRedirects if redirect_limit < 0

    self.response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))

    logger.info "redirect limit: #{redirect_limit}"
    logger.info "response code: #{response.code}"
    logger.debug "response body: #{response.body}"

    if response.kind_of?(Net::HTTPRedirection)      
      self.url = redirect_url
      self.redirect_limit -= 1

      logger.info "redirect found, headed to #{url}"
      resolve
    end

    self.body = response.body
    self
  end

  def redirect_url
    if response['location'].nil?
      response.body.match(/<a href=\"([^>]+)\">/i)[1]
    else
      response['location']
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to actually parse the content of the response. You can't do it with just handling headers.
So:

**Option 1**

Use [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) instead, which automatically follows redirects as well as meta redirects when `follow_meta_refresh` is set to true.

**Option 2**

Use something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to manually parse the actual response, and search for the meta tag that way.